# Prologでは再帰的に処理する方法と、findallでリストを生成する方法があると聞きました。findallの使い方を教えてください。

Tags: prolog

Prologでは再帰的に処理する方法と、findallでリストを生成する方法があると聞きました。
下に、再帰的な処理のプログラムがありますが、  findallを使うプログラムの書き方を教えて下さい。

```
%  
%  <<問題>>  
%  初心者向きのPrologの問題。100個の乱数値(0-99)をリストに生成してください。  
%  乱数値(0-99)は _乱数値 is random(100) で取れることとしてください。  
%  
%  初心者でない人には、「あなたは、何通りのプログラムパターンが脳裏を過ぎりますか？」  
%  


'100個の乱数値(0-99)をリストに生成します'(_乱数リスト) :-  
    '100個の'(_乱数リスト),  
    '乱数値(0-99)をリストに生成します'(_乱数リスト).  

'100個の'(_乱数リスト) :-  
    length(_乱数リスト,100).  

'乱数値(0-99)をリストに生成します'([]).  
'乱数値(0-99)をリストに生成します'([_乱数値|R]) :-  
    _乱数値 is random(100),  
    '乱数値(0-99)をリストに生成します'(R).
```

Comment: 地の文とサンプルコードを、それぞれ適切にマークアップしてはいただけないでしょうか?

Comment: コード部分は半角スペースを4つ入れることで綺麗に整形されるようになります。また、タイトルは長文を避け簡潔な説明が望ましいです。回答を得ている他の方の質問もご覧になると、参考になると思います。

Comment: コードは入力した後でコードの部分をテキスト選択して入力ボックスの上にある`{}`ボタンを押すことでも各行の頭にスペース4つ入れることができます。
あらかじめ加工しておいてもいいですし、やりやすい方法を使うと良いと思います。

Comment: タイトルには聞きたいことを完結に書きましょう。今回でいえば「再帰的な処理」はタイトルにまで書く必要があったかどうかです。「Prologでfindallを使ってリストを生成する方法」ではダメですか？本文は背景なども丁寧に書いたほうがいいですが、タイトルにいろいろ書くとノイズとなり逆効果となる事も。
タイトルであって本文の1行目ではないのです。

Answer (score 4):

指示してばかりも気が引ける部分があったので、ちょっとprologに挑戦してみました。

環境は以下の通り:

- windows 8.1 pro x64
- SWI-Prolog 6.6.6 for Windows XP/Vista/7/8 64-bit edition

初心者なので用語などが異なるかもしれませんがご容赦ください。

まず個人的な好みで英字変数名が好きなのでまずご提示のコードをを書き換えました（内容は同じです。並びが違うぐらいです）。

sample.plg

```
set_random_value_to_each_item_of_list([]).
set_random_value_to_each_item_of_list([_r|R]) :-
  _r is random(100),
  set_random_value_to_each_item_of_list(R).

gen_100_random_list(R) :-
  create_list_have_100_items(R),
  set_random_value_to_each_item_of_list(R).

create_list_have_100_items(R) :-
  length(R, 100).  % この部分適用において、Rとはこれがtrueになるようなリスト
                   %    -> 100個の任意のtermを持つリスト
```

実行するには(`?-` がSWI-Prologのプロンプト)

```
?- ['X:/path/to/file/sample.plg'].
?- gen_100_random_list(X).
X = [34, 63, 65, 82, 56, 75, 17, 0, 87|...].
```

---

で、これをfindall/3でということですが、

```
?- findall(X, (length(ELst,100), member(_X, ELst), X is random(100)), L).
```

または

```
?- findall(X, (numlist(1, 100, NLst), member(_X, NLst), X is random(100)), L).
```

で取ることができました。

プロシージャでは

```
gen_100_random_with_findall(L) :-
  findall(X, (length(ELst,100), member(_X, ELst), X is random(100)), L).

gen_100_random_with_findall2(L) :-
  findall(X, (numlist(1, 100, NLst), member(_X, NLst), X is random(100)), L).
```

として再読み込みして実行

```
?- ['X:/path/to/file/sample.plg'].

?- gen_100_random_with_findall(R).
R = [70, 73, 47, 53, 63, 56, 64, 82, 29|...].

?- gen_100_random_with_findall2(R).
R = [52, 39, 66, 39, 16, 94, 52, 56, 88|...].
```

期待通り動作していることを確認しています。

---

必要かどうかわかりませんが、解説としては、
たとえば、

```
a(1).
a(2).
a(3).
```

という定義があれば、

```
?- a(X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.
```

なので、

```
?- findall(X, a(X), L).
L=[1,2,3]
```

が取れます。ここで Xを aに適用せずに Xは2であると定義すれば
Xは常に2になる一方で aは何を渡していても3回結果を返すので、

```
?- findall(X, (a(_), X is 2), L).
L=[2,2,2]
```

という事になります。
random(100)で乱数が取れることはわかっているので、
あとはaの代わりに100個返す方法をさえあればよく、それは lengthとnumlistを使って実現して、回答に示した形になったというわけです。